# Online Service for measuring IQ

Tags: api, web-apis, saas

I'm seraching for an online service (with an API) that allows me to measure these types of intelligence:

1. Verbal / linguistic
2. Logic / mathematic
3. Visual / spatial
4. Interpersonal
5. Intrapersonal
6. Creativity

On a first step we will be using the online service for our hiring process, and on a second step, we need to integrate it to our own recruiting platform, so an API is a must.

I've searched on the Internet, and I haven't find a decent, modern online IQ testing system.